Generate protected zip file from local file and upload to server - Angular
I need to upload a file to a server from my Angular project, but I need this file to be protected (e.g. in a zip with a password).
I'm trying to use archiver-zip-encrypted, but being pure js I have some problem with using the example code. For starters, when I put the line
const archiver = require('archiver');


it's giving me a lot of errors that can't resolve seemingly unrelated things. For example:
./node_modules/archiver-utils/file.js:9:11-26 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Angular\EmailCenter\node_modules\archiver-utils'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

I've tried to use other libraries, but I haven't found any native to Angular.
